# Problems setting the ServiceName of a Windows Service

Tags: service

I have created a Windows Service via Visual Studio 2019.

The Visual Studio project's solution is (for the purposes of this question):

> ProductSyncService

So it was no surprise to find that the name displayed in Services.msc was this.

I would like to change it to:

Product Sync Service

I first set the Service Name property of serviceInstaller1, but that didn't work:
[image]

so I then tried setting it via the code as well (belt & braces), but that is not working either:
[image]

Despite doing a 'Clean' and then a rebuild and a re-install, Services.msc still shows it with the concatenated name.

I should add that I'm using Advanced Installer to create the MSI and that it has no references to the concatenated name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually found that there is indeed ServiceName property within Advanced Installer that was overriding the values in my Visual Studio project.

Easy to change and it's working fine now.